# Django getting the revisions

Tags: django

I am working on a Django project where in a model file I have a field called 'status' which is a choice field.

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (StudentProfileStatus.NEW, _('New')),
    (StudentProfileStatus.IMPORTED, _('Imported')),
    (StudentProfileStatus.MISSING_INFORMATION, _('Missing Information')),
    (StudentProfileStatus.INTERVIEW_SCHEDULED, _('Interview scheduled')),
    (StudentProfileStatus.REJECTED, _('Rejected')),
    (StudentProfileStatus.ACCEPTED, _('Accepted into Pool')),
    (StudentProfileStatus.PAUSED, _('Paused')),
    (StudentProfileStatus.OUTBOARDED, _('Outboarded'))

status = models.CharField(
    _('Status'),
    max_length=50,
    choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
    default=StudentProfileStatus.default()
)
```

I am sending an auto generated email as soon as 'Accepted into pool' choice option is selected by the admin for the first time.I am using post_save signal for that.Now in case an admin selects another choice option for e.g. 'Paused',saves it but later again reverts back to the 'Accepted into the pool' choice I don't want the mail to be sent out again.Is there any way where I can get all previous saved values for the 'status' field and check if 'Accepted into Pool' was already saved before so that there is no need to send out the mail again? One possible option which I could think of is django-revisions.

Comment: historic values of model fields are not stored anywhere unless you add some specific code to do so. this one looks good https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion

Comment: I would add a simple "mail_sent" boolean field. Unless you the status history for things as well.

Comment: @Yuri-Could you please elaborate a bit more on how simply a mail_sent field could do the job in my case?